# Deploy SpringBoot Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deploy

Estou com problemas para fazer deploy da minha aplicação SpringBoot no tomcat em um VPS linux.

O servidor está funcionando porém os links para resources e outras paginas sem ser a index estão quebrados 
[[image: Aplicação deployada[1]]

```
   <
        <groupId>com.eduq</groupId>
        <artifactId>eduq-web-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>eduq-web-app</name>
        <description>EduQ Web Application</description>



        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                 </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>


            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
                <version>0.36</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.json</groupId>
               <artifactId>json</artifactId>
               <version>20080701</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <thymeleaf.version>3.0.11.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
            <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
            <tomcat.version>9.0.24</tomcat.version>

        </properties>

    </project>

spring.thymeleaf.mode=html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.resources.add-mappings=true

server.servlet.contextPath = /

#datasource
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eduq_v2
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

#jpa/hibernate
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Fix Postgres JPA Error:
# Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

Comment: Você desenvolveu autoembarcado e na hora de ir pra produção foi através de um servidor provido? (aka não auto-provisionado?)

Comment: exatamente, mas agora não sei como resolver, olhei varios tutorias e não consegui

Comment: Possivelmente os links para os recursos estão absolutos relativos a raiz do serviço e você está fazendo um deploy em um endereço que não seja a raiz do tomcat. Recomendo tentar subir num tomcat em teste (que não seja o autoembarcado) para ver o comportamento. Também vale olhar nos logs do tomcat quais os recursos estão sendo acessados. Já passei por algo semelhante e não lembro do contorno, mas eu o fiz em teste local ainda

Comment: Já tive um problema parecido, ele ocorria por conta de um filtro de autenticação. Compare alguma versão recente que estava funcionando e veja se ocorreu alguma alteração em uma classe que implementa  implements ContainerRequestFilter ou uma equivalente em springBoot

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado , vou dar uma olhada

Comment: @cpll vou verificar

Comment: tenta remontar o ambiente. Faz o clone dele novamente.

Comment: já fiz ainda não deu certo